# Crashes after printing elements

Tags: c, arrays

My program crashes at runtime with the following error:

> "Exception thrown at 0x777433D5 (ntdll.dll) in caza.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000003."

What went wrong?

I've tried with that free function at main and without it and experienced the same error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct Dreptunghi
{
    int x1, y1, x2, y2;
}Dreptunghi;

void readElements(Dreptunghi* pDreptunghi, int nDreptunghi)
{


    for (int i = 0; i < nDreptunghi; ++i)
    {
        printf("Introduceti valorile pentru dreptunghiul %d \n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d %d %d %d",
            &pDreptunghi[i].x1,
            &pDreptunghi[i].y1,
            &pDreptunghi[i].x2,
            &pDreptunghi[i].y2);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

void printElements(Dreptunghi* pDreptunghi, int nDreptunghi)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nDreptunghi; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d %d %d %d\n", 
        pDreptunghi[i].x1, 
        pDreptunghi[i].y1, 
        pDreptunghi[i].x2, 
        pDreptunghi[i].y2);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Dreptunghi* pDreptunghi = NULL;
    int n=0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    pDreptunghi = (Dreptunghi*)malloc(n+1);
    readElements(pDreptunghi, n);
    printElements(pDreptunghi, n);
    free(pDreptunghi);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just reading the title gives me a hint about UB...

Comment: You need to allocate room for `n` objects of the correct type, not for `n` bytes.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: It's probably not the direct cause of your problem, but you'd do well to read and understand [the question on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in C](/q/605845).

Answer (score 4):

change

```
pDreptunghi = (Dreptunghi*)malloc(n+1);
```

to

```
pDreptunghi = malloc( (sizeof(*pDreptunghi)*n) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not allocating enough memory here ,you need to assign memory that equals size of structure multiply by number of element :

pDreptunghi = (Dreptunghi*)malloc((sizeof(*pDreptunghi)*n)+1);